Stream through a portion of a 2D array in Java
Let's say you have a matrix
[[1,2,5],[3,4,6]] and you need to work with the first two elements of each row together [1,2,3,4]. You don't want to store this in memory or use nested loops. Is there a way to achieve this using streams in Java?

"You don't want to store this in memory" does your array is stored in memory?

The 2d array is, yeah

What do you even want to achieve?

Here is example
int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 6}};

Arrays.stream(arr)
        .flatMapToInt(a -> Arrays.stream(a).limit(2))
        .forEach(System.out::println);

EDIT Here is summary of all the methods:
@Fork(value = 1, warmups = 1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class MainTest {
    public static final int FIRST_SIZE = 1000;
    private static final int SECOND_SIZE = 100000;
    private int[][] arr;

    @Setup(Level.Trial)
    public void setUp() {
        arr = IntStream.range(0, FIRST_SIZE)
                .mapToObj(x -> new Random().ints(SECOND_SIZE).toArray())
                .toArray(int[][]::new);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void loop(Blackhole blackhole) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                sum += arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        blackhole.consume(sum);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void singleLoop(Blackhole blackhole) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < FIRST_SIZE * SECOND_SIZE; i++) {
            sum += arr[i / SECOND_SIZE][i % SECOND_SIZE];
        }
        blackhole.consume(sum);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void enhancedLoop(Blackhole blackhole) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int[] ints : arr) {
            for (int anInt : ints) {
                sum += anInt;
            }
        }
        blackhole.consume(sum);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void stream(Blackhole blackhole) {
        int sum = Arrays.stream(arr)
                .flatMapToInt(a -> Arrays.stream(a))
                .sum();
        blackhole.consume(sum);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void parallelStream(Blackhole blackhole) {
        int sum = Arrays.stream(arr)
                .parallel()
                .flatMapToInt(a -> Arrays.stream(a))
                .sum();
        blackhole.consume(sum);
    }


    @Benchmark
    public void mapMultiToInt(Blackhole blackhole) {
        int sum = Arrays.stream(arr).mapMultiToInt((row, consumer) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                consumer.accept(row[i]);
            }
        }).sum();

        blackhole.consume(sum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }
}

And here is result on my machine:
Benchmark                       Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
MainTest.enhancedLoop           avgt   15  0.047 ± 0.003   s/op
MainTest.loop                   avgt   15  0.063 ± 0.012   s/op
MainTest.mapMultiToInt          avgt   15  0.060 ± 0.006   s/op
MainTest.parallelStream         avgt   15  0.047 ± 0.003   s/op
MainTest.singleLoop             avgt   15  0.297 ± 0.020   s/op
MainTest.stream                 avgt   15  0.051 ± 0.005   s/op


Thanks! Great solution. I used flatMapToInt(n -> Arrays.stream(n).limit(2))

Instead of a flatMap with a combination of mapToObj you coud just use flatMapToInt and instead of limit you could use the overload with the 3 arg parameters of Arrays.stream. Something like Arrays.stream(arr).flatMapToInt(a -> Arrays.stream(a, 0, 2)).forEach....

True, this one is useful for restricting the start index

@Asmir Agree. I made most basic implementation. It clearly have lot of space to improve.

BTW mapToObj(x -> x) is same as .boxed() (and most basic would be plain for loop IMHO)

@user85421 nice catch with .boxed(). I never use that part of API in real life, so I forgot that it exists. OP explicitly asked for no loops, so streams it is.

@DominicJ  "Thanks! Great solution. "  Then you should consider accepting the answer.  See the check mark to the left.  Note, you can only accept one answer.

@WJS fair enough . Today I learned mapMultiToInt and I'm not sure how I feel about it.

You pay a heavy price for streams in general.

No, you don't. They are surprisingly lightweight. And if you look into source code you'll see it creates stream anyway.

@talexmovedtoCodidact  I owe you an apology.  I rechecked my test and made a mistake.  The nested loop is faster but but only twice as fast.  Mea culpa.

My test says it is only 10%. Can you show me yours?

You should use Arrays.stream(a, 0, 2) instead of Arrays.stream(a).limit(2), really.

This would let you do it from any part of the rows as well as avoid the overhead of creating another stream.  Use mapMultiToInt.
int[][] matrix = {{1,2,5},{3,4,6}};

int first = 0;
int last = 1;

int[] result = Arrays.stream(matrix).mapMultiToInt((row, consumer)-> {
    for(int i=first; i <= last; i++) {
        consumer.accept(row[i]);
    }
}).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

prints
[1, 2, 3, 4]


"overhead of creating another stream." since mapMultiToInt create buffer and collect all accepted elements before continuing I hardly can call it a win :)

I was just going by the one of the JEP talking points and it says it in the JavaDoc,  But it also has other advantages.  Selectively putting items on the stream, or multiples of the same one.

There are more straightforward ways to achieve that. And no on reads JavDaocs.

"And no on reads JavDaocs" Well, I do.

    String[][] matrix = new String[][]{
            {"11111", "why ", "did ", "I ", "lose ", "reputation ", "11111", "11111"},
            {"22222", "points ", "for ", "this ", "question? ", "(dk)", "11111", "22222"}};
    Arrays.stream(matrix, 0, 2)
            .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s, 1, 6))
            .forEach(System.out::print);
}


Probably because your answer doesn't actually answer your question. It uses different type, have wrong output. Also it just copies other answers.

@talexmovedtoCodidact  I believe the OP is asking about his question.  And I don't know why it was downvoted.  The reason was needs more focus.  But I thought it was okay.

I know it's not exactly what you're asking for, but since it's simple and faster....
int[][] arr = { { 1, 2, 5 }, { 3, 4, 6 } }; 

void run( int arr[][] ) {
   int limit = 2, j = 0, k = 0;
   for( int i = 0; i < arr.length * limit; i ++ ) {
      System.out.println( arr[ j ][ k ] );
      k++;
      if( k == limit ) {
         j++; 
         k = 0;
      }
   }
}

comparison vs:
Arrays.stream( arr ).flatMapToInt( a -> Arrays.stream( a ).limit( 2 ));

Stream -> 1378919 // best result obtained
for -> 31638 // worst result obtained
I could not compare against
  int first = 0;
  int last = 1;
  int[] result = Arrays.stream( arr ).mapMultiToInt( ( row, consumer ) -> {
     for( int i = first; i <= last; i ++ ) {
        consumer.accept( row[ i ] );
     }
  } ).toArray();

because I don't have an updated version of the JVM.

System.out.println( arr[ j ][ k ] ) can be replaced by System.out.println( arr[ i / limit ][ i % limit ] ) so you don't need to use if in the loop.

Maestro... noticeably faster, and cleaner... perfect!!!

OK. Since this has evolved into performance, here is what I did.  Note that this type of test just gives a general indication of performance.  A much better solution is to use Java Microbench Harness to evaluate performance and specific bottlenecks.
In my results using Windows 10 intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz w/12 GB ram it printed the following;
Starting
nestedLoops  -  3.180s
oneLoop      -  9.633s
arrayStream  -  6.433s
true
42000000 42000000 42000000

The test code

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();

    int[][] matrix = IntStream.range(0, 300_000)
            .mapToObj(i -> r.ints(200, 0, 200).toArray())
            .toArray(int[][]::new);

    int first = 10;
    int last = 150;
    int N = 30;
    int[] r1 = null;
    int[] r2 = null;
    int[] r3 = null;
    System.out.println("Starting");
    {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            r1 = nestedLoops(matrix, first, last);
        }
        System.out.printf("%-12s -  %.3fs%n", "nestedLoops",
                (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1e9);
    }
    {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            r2 = oneLoop(matrix, first, last);
        }
        System.out.printf("%-12s -  %.3fs%n", "oneLoop",
                (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1e9);

    }
    {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            r3 = arrayStream(matrix, first, last);
        }
        System.out.printf("%-12s -  %.3fs%n", "arrayStream",
                (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1e9);

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(r1, r2) && Arrays.equals(r1, r3));
    System.out.println(r1.length + " " + r2.length + " " + r2.length);
}
// nested loops
static int[] nestedLoops(int arr[][], int first, int last) {
    int k = 0;
    int limit = last - first;
    int[] result = new int[arr.length * limit];
    for (int[] ar : arr) {
        for (int i = first; i < last; i++) {
            result[k++] = ar[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
// single loop
static int[] oneLoop(int arr[][], int first, int last) {
    int limit = last - first;
    int[] result = new int[arr.length * limit];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length * limit; i++) {
        result[i] = arr[i / limit][i % limit + first];
    }
    return result;
}

// stream with Arrays.stream()
static int[] arrayStream(int[][] matrix, int first, int last) {
   return Arrays.stream(matrix).
         flatMapToInt(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr, first, last)).toArray();
}


You are right about proper benchmark harness. Your test need warmup. Looks like JIT didn't kick in properly.
